# elegant way to subtract a number of every list element

Tags: haskell

I recently ran into following problem: Given a list of numbers, I want to subtract a constant from every entry of this list. The natural but wrong thing to do is

```
map (-3) [5,6,7]
```

Here the `-` is not interpreted a binary function but as an unary negation operator.

I found following workarounds:

```
map (+(-3)) [5,6,7]
map ((+)(-3)) [5,6,7]
map (flip (-) 3) [5,6,7]
```

**Question :** Is there a more *elegant* way to do this that avoids this unnecessary pile of parenthesis?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope, sorry. You have the `subtract` function, but it's not shorter.

```
Prelude> map (subtract 3) [3,4,5]
[0,1,2]
```

Comment: I somehow have the feeling that you magically smelled that I was coming from PPCG  :D

Comment: @flawr might have seen you around on PPCG :)